# Git command-line message when running for the first time

Tags: xcode, git, command-line

Every time I try to do anything with `git` on command-line for after launching terminal, I get a wall of messages I don't really know what they mean.

```
$ git status
2017-06-26 10:32:15.837 xcodebuild[2977:628414] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/OMQuickHelp.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2017-06-26 10:32:15.839 xcodebuild[2977:628414] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/GitDiff.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2017-06-26 10:32:15.840 xcodebuild[2977:628414] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/DefaultMarginDisabler.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2017-06-26 10:32:15.841 xcodebuild[2977:628414] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/CocoaPodUI.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2017-06-26 10:32:15.842 xcodebuild[2977:628414] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/CocoaPods.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2017-06-26 10:32:15.845 xcodebuild[2977:628414] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID DFFB3951-EB0A-4C09-9DAC-5F2D28CC839C for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
On branch master
```

Now, I know it is complaining about `.xcplugin`s but this never happened before I updated my `Xcode` from the AppStore to latest `8.3.3 (8E3004b)`. I completed `Install Plugin` phase right after as well.

Also, important to note, this does not show up after the first `git` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed it by deleting all plug-ins, which makes sense as Xcode does not allow 3rd party plug-ins anymore. This command fixed it:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/*`